# File.Delete Preventing Method From Continuing

Tags: c#, wpf

I am attempting to check if an `Image` exists for a `Company`. If it does exist I would like to delete the existing `Image` and replace it with a new one. To do this;

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(new Action(() =>
{
    if (File.Exists(destFile))
    {
        File.Delete(destFile);
    }

    File.Copy(sourceFile, destFile, true);

}), DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle);
```

I've placed `MessageBox` in to try and debug and after the `File.Delete` methods and they never show which leads me to believe that they are preventing the method from running any further.

Is there any reason why this would prevent my method from continuing at all?

Comment: FWIW, `File.Copy(sourceFile, destFile, true)` already overwrites if the file exists, so you wouldn't need to do `File.Delete`.

Comment: There's no need for the `if (File.Exists(destfile))`. Just call `File.Delete(destFile)`. If the file exists, it is deleted. If it doesn't exist, `File.Delete` fails silently. But why are you deleting the file in the first place, when the call to `File.Copy` will overwrite an existing file anyway?

Comment: What are you trying to debug? Is the `File.Copy` not working? Perhaps you should run your program in the debugger. Set a breakpoint at `File.Copy`.

Comment: Your problem is the `Priority` that you set for this task, it should be `Background` at least, rather than `ContextIdle`.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the Image file or the folder in which it is present is not in use.
Try Clean then Build and then Run your project.

Comment: "Hope" isn't a very effective development practice.